# How to correctly estimate the transaction logs used in one INSERT operation for SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

I plan to insert large amount of records (hundred thousands of rows containing blob PDF data) into a table (one time) and I would like to make sure the disk the database is on has enough space beforehand. I also know that while inserting, the transaction log also takes additional space. My question is how to correctly estimate how much space the transaction log will take? Is there a rule of thumb? Is transaction log going to take the same amount of space as the data (in the current batch) takes? Or it is not possible?

To narrow down the scope of this question,

- we are using simple recovery model
- let's not consider minimally logged operations

Thanks.

Comment: If you know it is going to be an extremely large number of changes/records then break it into manageable batches which would work for you because of the chosen recovery model assuming you are not wrapping your batches in a single transaction.

Comment: As well as the space actually used (that could be estimated by testing and looking at `fn_dblog`) also take into account [Each transaction reserves space on the transaction log to make sure that enough log space exists to support a rollback that is caused by either an explicit rollback statement or if an error is encountered.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-log-architecture-and-management-guide?view=sql-server-ver15#Logical_Arch)

Comment: Try to get it minimally logged if you can (I know you don;t want to consider it but it does help a lot), then the transaction log should be much smaller, see https://sqlperformance.com/2019/05/sql-performance/minimal-logging-empty-clustered and https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/sql-server-2016-minimal-logging-and-impact-of-the-batchsize-in/ba-p/385537

Comment: Thank you all for your input!